# Why do Radio buttons always send first radio button's value?

Tags: php, post, radio-button

I have two radio buttons which I fill their values dynamically and I select any of them I get first value.

HTML Side:

```
    $haber_modulleri[0] = 'Duyuru';
    $haber_modulleri[1] = 'Manşet'; 
    <?php foreach($haber_modulleri as $key => $modul):?>
         <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">         
         <input type="radio" name="haber_tur" value="<?= $key;?>" <?php if(isset($haber->haber_tur) AND $haber->haber_tur == $key) echo "checked"?> />          
         <label for="<?php echo $key;?>" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:13px;"><?php echo $modul;?></label>         
         </div>           
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Rendered HTML Side:

```
  <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">                  
       <input type="radio" name="haber_tur" value="0"  />                  
       <label for="0" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:13px;">Duyuru</label>                 
  </div>                                                    
  <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
     <input type="radio" name="haber_tur" value="1"  /> 
     <label for="1" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:13px;">Manşet</label>
  </div>
```

PHP POST Side:

```
$haber_tur = $db->escape($_POST['haber_tur']);
echo $_POST['haber_tur'] . "\r\n";
echo $haber_tur . "TUR" . PHP_EOL ;
```

My variable call $haber_tur is always zero, whichever I select.
Echos' result are "0 0TUR".

Comment: Rendered HTML of the radio buttons please.

Comment: I added rendered HTML code.

Comment: This is working fine to me

Comment: But not me it is always zero. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you add all HTML form ?

Comment: It is very long. So I add it jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcsN/36FWZ/

Comment: You have another element with same name `<select id="haber_tur" name="haber_tur">`

Comment: ^ that's exactly the issue, it's returns the value of the last element with name `haber_tur`, you should give it another name. Good find @Paul

Comment: Thanks my friends it's not my project I continue and I never think about it. It is in other panel form. Really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are passing `$key` instead of the value, do:

```
<input type="radio" name="haber_tur" value="<?= $modul;?>"
```

The content of the `value` attribute here is the one that gets passed to PHP when you call `$_POST['haber_tur']`.

Comment: I want send key for value, becuase my field is bit. So it is muts 0 or 1. My problem is when I select second radio button, I get 0 again like I select first.

Comment: this doesn't explain why he doesn't get `1` when he selects the second button

Comment: Could you try `echo $_POST['haber_tur']` before the `$db->escape()` line. Also do you have only two of those radio buttons or more on the same page?

Comment: I have only two. And When I write value="<?= $modul;?>" I get 0 again.$db->escape is ez-SQL function. Again "0 0 TUR".

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ Do a `var_dump($_POST);` at the first line and tell me what you see.

Comment: ["haber_tur"]=> string(1) "0" is about our subject.

Comment: radio buttons in the same form will only allow one of them to be selected at anytime. I'll check your code real fast and try and fix it.

Comment: ok question, why are you using the index value for the value of your input value attribute? Your using a foreach loop on a numerical array. Post your full code so I can see what is all going on. you should have the correct data being sent via post since they have the same name. $db-escape() would also be part of the problem.

Comment: @user3587554 You should read the comments under the question, he had a `<select>` with the same name as the radio.